# MVVMLight Observable object Set()

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, mvvm-light

I have a WPF Application that uses MVVM Light. I have used there Set() property in my ViewModel properties as this means i don't have to RaisePropertyNotify myself. 
This has worked for me perfectly until i have had to create a new View and ViewModel, Now when i change a property in the ViewModel my view is not getting updated even tho i can see in the call stack that RaisePropertyChanged is being called.
Having looked through the code i can't see what is different or why one is working and one is not. Is there something i may need to look for or has anyone else experienced a similar issue?

My property look like this

```
private bool _isProgressBarEnabled = true;
    public bool IsProgressBarEnabled
    {
        get { return _isProgressBarEnabled; }
        set { Set(() => IsProgressBarEnabled, ref _isProgressBarEnabled, value); }
    }
```

This is the stub for the Set() property of MVVMLight

```
protected bool Set<T>(Expression<Func<T>> propertyExpression, ref T field, T newValue);
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you certain that the element is actually bound to that property? Check the Output Window for binding errors.

Comment: All the bindings are correct, I have managed to get a work around for now but it's weird that the code works in one page and not another. I had tried raising the RaisePropertyChanged event which didn't work for me because the WPF Application is run within a Winforms Application. The call i had to use was System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents() in my Set method and this is working for now.

Comment: This turned out to be a treading issue, the process i started that the progress bar was being used for was taking up so much resource that the UI never had a chance to update. Should have probably considered this sooner but in-case anyone else is having a similar issue its worth a look at the threading